# Inherit and not overriding attributes/methods when extending classes

Tags: javascript, marionette

To inherit and not overriding methods like `onRender/onShow/initialize`, I know I can use `prototype.onRender.apply()`.  But is there a cleaner way to inherit, instead of to write it every time?

Both console.log will be printed when `new MyView2() ... .show()`

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  onRender: function () {
    console.log('MyView onRender');
  }
});


var MyView2 = MyView.extend({
  onRender: function () {
    MyView.prototype.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('MyView2 onRender');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, in ES5 that's about as good as it gets and is used [all](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/9bdb9e61e149512bed829c9e8c839470df992978/src/collection-view.js#L450) [over](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/9bdb9e61e149512bed829c9e8c839470df992978/src/item-view.js#L12) [the place](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/9bdb9e61e149512bed829c9e8c839470df992978/src/view.js#L266) [internally](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/9bdb9e61e149512bed829c9e8c839470df992978/src/layout-view.js#L49) in Marionette - with Backbone the other option is to use [`__super__`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L1584) or transpile from ES6

```
var MyView2 = MyView.extend({
  onRender() {
    MyView2.__super__.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('MyView2 onRender');
  }
});
```

Comment: I never understand prototype and __super__ , but this is the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not sure that I got your question right, but you seem to look for the default inheritance mechanism:

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  onRender: function () {
    console.log('MyView onRender');
  }
});


var MyView2 = MyView.extend({
  // MyView2 will inherit onRender from MyView
});

MyView2.prototype.onRender === MyView.prototype.onRender // true
```

Comment: I think it is not what I mean.  In your code MyView2 will run MyView's onRender.  What I need is:  MyView2 to run 1) MyView's onRender, then 2) MyView2's onRender